# Downloading several files froma website with Perl

Tags: perl, download, www-mechanize, lwp

I began to mess around with the Web in Perl. I use Windows, and ActivePerl. I wrote a script, which downloads mp3 files (It's an archive of a radio talkshow, all legal, in case you're wondering :) ) It (in theory)

- parses a website
- collects all links pointing to an mp3 file to an array
- iterates through the array and downloads all files

However the script finds all the links, the array is OK, but downloads only one file. It must be a basic error, but I can't find it. Please point out my mistake, thank you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP::Simple;
use File::Basename;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );  
$mech->get("http://something_or_other.html");

my @mp3links = $mech->find_all_links(    
    tag       => "a",
    url_regex => qr/\.mp3$/,  
);  
print "\n";                 
foreach my $link (@mp3links) {  

    my $url       = $link->url();  
    my $localfile = basename($url);  
    my $localpath = "d:\\Downloads\\$localfile";

    print "$localfile\n";   
    getstore($url, $localpath);   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to check if @mp3links contains what you expect it to contain and that $localpath is generated correctly for each iteration?

Comment: Does it work if you change `getstore()` call to `warn "$url => $localpath\n"`? Did you do `print Dumper(\@mp3links)` before entering `foreach` loop?

Comment: Does the `print "$localfile\n"` statement show all of the files you expect?

Comment: @mp3links contains the Mechanize::Link objects. $localpath is generated correctly in each iteration. I added the `warn` line as @s0me0ne suggested. Now the download works. I don't get it yet :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, sorry guys. This had nothing to do with Perl. My internet connection was rather sh***y, the connection was always lost ehile downloading the first file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my $status = getstore($url, $localpath);
die "Error $status on $url" unless is_success($status);
```

Another possible culprit - 
if links contain query string (?-mark + params)
basename will not chop it off.
Problem is that this will make it invalid filename on windows.